# org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: PROFIL thrown by my integration test

Tags: integration-testing, datasource, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit, spring-boot-test

I am working with the following tables (I created a miniture of the DB cause it is so big)

[image]

In my Integration test I configured DBUnit to work with the following data sources:

```
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection={"mainDataSource", "securityDataSource"})
```

I also Specified mainDataSource as PRIMARY as follows:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "mainDataSource")
public DataSource appDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_MAINBASE_SCHEMA));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "securityDataSource")
public DataSource securityDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_SECURITY_SCHEMA));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
    return dataSource;
}
```

This is the error I get

```
org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: PROFIL

at org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap.add(OrderedTableNameMap.java:198)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:231)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:281)
at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any idea how to exclude the PROFIL table or the entire View Schema, because my DBUnit can still see it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**1.** Add `FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES` property:

```
DatabaseConfig config = dBConn.getConfig();
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

**2.** In your `dataset` you must add the schema name:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
 <SCHEMA.TABLENAME .../>
</dataset>
```

Note the dataset in uppercase.

Info: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AmbiguousTableNameException

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where do I add the 1st code? in the Datasource Bean definition ? or at the test initialization? and what is dBConn?

Comment: Add it where you have the database conection. dBConn is an IDatabaseConnection.

Comment: DatabaseConfig config = dBConn.getConfig();
config.setFeature().... not setProperty() :)